# Old heap gen space not being garbaged collected in Scala

Tags: java, scala, garbage-collection

I'm writing code in scala and I have a couple of methods that return extremely large arrays (size about 70000). I'm running something of the form:

```
object x {
def returnArray(y: Int): Array[Double] = {
... \\returns a large array
  }
def calculateAverage(largeArray: Array[Double]) : Double = {
...\\ takes the large array and calculates the average number.
  }
}
```

I noticed when running jconsole the eden and survivor spaces were GCing often and not too much memory was being used. However, the GC of the old gen space did nothing and there was a huge amount of memory being used.

Could this be due to the fact that the very large arrays are going directly into the Old Gen space and then because the arrays are return types of a method they aren't being dereferenced?

Comment: 70K elements is going to be around a MB, that will fit on even a cheap phone, so not "extremely large".  Did you mean 700 million elements which several GB?    BTW VisualVM or Flight recorder might be better.

Comment: jconsole and VisualVM create quite a bit of garbage just monitoring your application which would make it hard to see the difference. BTW are you sure a full collection occurred?

Comment: @PeterLawrey `Array[Double]` is the `double[]` in java terms

Comment: @Odomontois I am glad to be corrected. In that case the array uses about 560 KB which really would be hard to see.

Comment: It's hard to say without actual code. Can you share code demonstrating the problem? I'd probably make sure a full GC has occurred, then take a heap dump and then view it with a tool like http://www.eclipse.org/mat/

Answer (score 0):

Garbage collection is expensive. Are you running out of memory? If not, why should the system run such an expensive operation if all the memory gets released back to the OS anyway when your program ends?

As was mentioned in the comments, your array is about 560 kByte (547 KiByte) big. On most modern computers, keeping that much memory around a little longer than actually needed is not really a serious concern. And thus, the system will avoid running such an expensive operation if it doesn't make much of an impact anyway. (547 KiByte more or less is not really noticeable for a typical Scala program.)